Identify movie about neighborhood
Watched a movie a while back about neighborhood that a couple moved into. It seemed perfect at first and then they found out the neighborhood watch had security cameras in each house and watched everyone. Then the couple wanted to leave but they were caught and the husband got his legs chopped off. And the wife became weird like the rest of the neighborhood. She started to have this strange look and I think saying something like 'do you want to be my neighbor?' Or something along those lines not sure.  At the end there was a scene where you see a new family moving in and that wife was saying what a wonderful neighborhood it was and that her husband was in a war accident and does not like to show his injuries which is really the neighborhood leader or whatever that chopped them off. 
I tried searching for it a lot of times but no luck. Maybe not very popular or good but it's one of those things that keep bothering me and I want to know what it is called. 

Fear Itself episode "Community" 

Bobby (Brandon Routh) and Tracy (Shiri Appleby) believe they have found the perfect place to raise a family in the secured and closed community ran by Candace (Barbara Tyson). Not long after they moved in, Bobby starts to feel uneasy by the unusual and forced influence of the neighbors on his family life. And he will find out that perfection is unreachable...
  YEARS LATER. Tracy and her young son introduce a new couple to the neighborhood. She is the new Candace. Bobby, watching from the upstairs window, sits in a wheelchair ... his legs cut off at the knees.

